# React component inside component isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I am new to Reactjs and I simply can't make the Part component runs inside the Content component when using props. Is there a way to do it by editing the Part or the Content component without changing the  tag?
I know this is kinda easy for experienced React developers but I've been struggling with it for the past 2 hours without success. Can somebody help me?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const Part = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>{props.part} {props.exercises}</p>
  );
};

const Content = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Part part={props.part1} exercises={props.exercises1} />
      <Part part={props.part2} exercises={props.exercises2} />
      <Part part={props.part3} exercises={props.exercises3} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const part1 = 'Fundamentals of React';
  const exercises1 = 10;
  const part2 = 'Using props to pass data';
  const exercises2 = 7;
  const part3 = 'State of a component';
  const exercises3 = 14;

  return (
    <div>
      <Content />         
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

edit: improved formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-playground-forked-61z4y?file=/src/index.tsx)

Collect all the variables into an array of objects and pass it down the component tree

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Part = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>
      {props.part} {props.exercises}
    </p>
  );
};

const Content = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(part => <Part {...part} />)}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    { part: "Fundamentals of React", exercises: 10 },
    { part: "Using props to pass data", exercises: 7 },
    { part: "State of a component", exercises: 14 }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Content data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! That's what I was looking for!